# Is there any way to track an event using firebase in electron + react

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, electron

I want to ask about how to send an event using firebase & electron.js. A friend of mine has a problem when using firebase analytics and electron that it seems the electron doesn't send any event to the debugger console. When I see the network it seems the function doesn't send anything but the text successfully go in console. can someone help me to figure it? any workaround way will do, since he said he try to implement the solution in this topic

1. [firebase-analytics-log-event-not-working-in-production-build-of-electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660828/firebase-analytics-log-event-not-working-in-production-build-of-electron)
2. [electron-google-analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-google-analytics)

this is the error I got when Try to use A solution in Point 2

[image: the error I got when Using Lib in point 2]

For information, my friend used this for the boiler plate [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)

The solution above still failed. Can someone help me to solve this?

**EDIT 1:**

[image: This is the example of my code]

[image: If I run the code, it only gives a very basic screen of electron with the button to send the event]

As you can see in the image above, the first image is my friend's code when you run it, it will give a very basic example like in the image 2 with a button to send an event.

ah just for information He used this firebase package :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

Answer (score 3):

You can intercept HTTP protocol and handle your static content though the provided methods, it would allow you to use `http://` protocol for the content URLs. What should make Firebase Analytics work as provided in the first question.

### References

- [Protocol interception](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol) documentation.

### Example

This is an example of how you can serve local app as loaded by HTTP protocol and simulate regular browser work to use `http` protocol with bundled web application. This will allow you to add Firebase Analytics. It supports poorly HTTP data upload, but you can do it on your own depending on the goals.

**`index.js`**

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, protocol} = require('electron')
const http = require('http')
const {createReadStream, promises: fs} = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const {PassThrough} = require('stream')

const mime = require('mime')

const MY_HOST = 'somehostname.example'

app.whenReady()
.then(async () => {
  await protocol.interceptStreamProtocol('http', (request, callback) => {
    const url = new URL(request.url)
    const {hostname} = url

    const isLocal = hostname === MY_HOST

    if (isLocal) {
      serveLocalSite({...request, url}, callback)
    }
    else {
      serveRegularSite({...request, url}, callback)
    }
  })

  const win = new BrowserWindow()
  win.loadURL(`http://${MY_HOST}/index.html`)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
  app.exit(1)
})

async function serveLocalSite(request, callback) {
  try {
    const {pathname} = request.url
    const filepath = path.join(__dirname, path.resolve('/', pathname))
    const stat = await fs.stat(filepath)

    if (stat.isFile() !== true) {
      throw new Error('Not a file')
    }

    callback(
      createResponse(
        200,
        {
          'content-type': mime.getType(path.extname(pathname)),
          'content-length': stat.size,
        },
        createReadStream(filepath)
      )
    )
  }
  catch (err) {
    callback(
      errorResponse(err)
    )
  }
}

function serveRegularSite(request, callback) {
  try {
    console.log(request)
    const req = http.request({
      url: request.url,
      host: request.url.host,
      port: request.url.port,
      method: request.method,
      headers: request.headers,
    })

    if (req.uploadData) {
      req.write(request.uploadData.bytes)
    }

    req.on('error', (error) => {
      callback(
        errorResponse(error)
      )
    })

    req.on('response', (res) => {
      console.log(res.statusCode, res.headers)
      callback(
        createResponse(
          res.statusCode,
          res.headers,
          res,
        )
      )
    })

    req.end()
  }
  catch (err) {
    callback(
      errorResponse(err)
    )
  }
}

function toStream(body) {
  const stream = new PassThrough()

  stream.write(body)
  stream.end()

  return stream
}

function errorResponse(error) {
  return createResponse(
    500,
    {
      'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=utf8',
    },
    error.stack
  )
}

function createResponse(statusCode, headers, body) {
  if ('content-length' in headers === false) {
    headers['content-length'] = Buffer.byteLength(body)
  }
  return {
    statusCode,
    headers,
    data: typeof body === 'object' ? body : toStream(body),
  }
}
```

- `MY_HOST` is any non-existent host (like `something.example`) or host that is controlled by admin (in my case it could be `electron-app.rumk.in`). This host will serve as replacement for localhost.

**`index.html`**

```html
<html>
<body>
   Hello
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Paul, thank you for your response, but, could you provide some example? My friend don't understand which "Content" and when it's going to be intercepted
or maybe some repo link would be very helpful!, ah I already Edited the thread to give the code example of my friend's project

Comment: @RakishFrisky I've added complete example of how to serve files bundled with Electron, like if they were loaded via network.